# Unable to connect to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, windows-server-2012-r2

While trying to connect through PHP it displays

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'bookedscheduler' in C:\wamp\www\booked\lib\Database\MySQL\MySqlConnection.php on line 52

Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\booked\lib\Database\MySQL\MySqlConnection.php on line 53

Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\booked\lib\Database\MySQL\MySqlConnection.php on line 54

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\booked\lib\Database\MySQL\MySqlConnection.php:53) in C:\wamp\www\booked\Pages\Page.php on line 138

My config.php 
database connection

```
$conf['settings']['database']['type'] = 'mysql';

$conf['settings']['database']['user'] = 'booked_user'; 

$conf['settings']['database']['password'] = '';

$conf['settings']['database']['hostspec'] = '127.0.0.1'; 

$conf['settings']['database']['name'] = 'bookedscheduler';
```

Mysqlconnection.php file

```
class MySqlConnection implements IDbConnection
{
private $_dbUser = '';
private $_dbPassword = '';
private $_hostSpec = '';
private $_dbName = '';

private $_db = null;
private $_connected = false;

/**
 * @param string $dbUser
 * @param string $dbPassword
 * @param string $hostSpec
 * @param string $dbName
 */
public function __construct($dbUser, $dbPassword, $hostSpec, $dbName)
{
    $this->_dbUser = $dbUser;
    $this->_dbPassword = $dbPassword;
    $this->_hostSpec = $hostSpec;
    $this->_dbName = $dbName;
}

public function Connect()
{
    if ($this->_connected && !is_null($this->_db))
    {
        return;
    }

    $this->_db = mysqli_connect($this->_hostSpec, $this->_dbUser, $this->_dbPassword,$this->_dbName);
    $selected = mysqli_select_db($this->_db, $this->_dbName);
    mysqli_set_charset($this->_db, 'utf8');

    if (!$this->_db || !$selected)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error connecting to database\nError: " . mysql_error());
        Log::Error("Error connecting to database\n%s",  mysql_error());
    }

    $this->_connected = true;
}

public function Disconnect()
{
    mysqli_close($this->_db);
    $this->_db = null;
    $this->_connected = false;
}

public function Query(ISqlCommand $sqlCommand)
{
    mysqli_set_charset($this->_db, 'utf8');
    $mysqlCommand = new MySqlCommandAdapter($sqlCommand, $this->_db);

    Log::Sql('MySql Query: ' . str_replace('%', '%%', $mysqlCommand->GetQuery()));

    $result = mysqli_query($this->_db, $mysqlCommand->GetQuery());

    $this->_handleError($result);

    return new MySqlReader($result);
}

public function LimitQuery(ISqlCommand $command, $limit, $offset = 0)
{
    return $this->Query(new MySqlLimitCommand($command, $limit, $offset));
}

public function Execute(ISqlCommand $sqlCommand)
{
    mysqli_set_charset($this->_db, 'utf8');
    $mysqlCommand = new MySqlCommandAdapter($sqlCommand, $this->_db);

    Log::Sql('MySql Execute: ' . str_replace('%', '%%', $mysqlCommand->GetQuery()));

    $result = mysqli_query($this->_db, $mysqlCommand->GetQuery());

    $this->_handleError($result);
}

public function GetLastInsertId()
{
    return mysqli_insert_id($this->_db);
}

private function _handleError($result, $sqlCommand = null)
{
    if (!$result)
    {
        if ($sqlCommand != null)
        {
            echo $sqlCommand->GetQuery();
        }
        throw new Exception('There was an error executing your query\n' .  mysql_error());

        Log::Error("Error executing MySQL query %s",  mysql_error());
    }
    return false;
}
}

class MySqlLimitCommand extends SqlCommand
{
/**
 * @var \ISqlCommand
 */
private $baseCommand;

private $limit;
private $offset;

public function __construct(ISqlCommand $baseCommand, $limit, $offset)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->baseCommand = $baseCommand;
    $this->limit = $limit;
    $this->offset = $offset;

    $this->Parameters = $baseCommand->Parameters;
}

public function GetQuery()
{
    return $this->baseCommand->GetQuery() . sprintf(" LIMIT %s OFFSET %s",  $this->limit, $this->offset);
}

}
?>
```

Please someone guide me in this regard

Comment: Can you show the code for your db connection in page.php/MySqlConnection.php ?

Comment: `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database ` <--- It doesn't seem that any user is being entered on mysql connect. Post your `MySqlConnection.php` file.

Comment: make sure your db user and password is correct. Also you have to throw exception before select_db or set_charset ..

Comment: User is root and no password

Comment: if user is root why your configs show it as booked_user?

Comment: sorry user is booked_user only no password

Comment: Please show the code where the instance of class `MySqlConnection` is created, so the usage of the `new` command. It is pretty clear from the code shown so far and the error message that your constructor does _not_ receive the configuration values as intended. It uses blank values instead. Not only the user name is missing, also the host name is the default `localhost`, not the ip address you specified.

Comment: I installed the same thing in windows 7 and its working fine there. Now I'm trying to install it in Windows server 2012 R2. Now I'm facing issues.

Comment: Is it because of Port number or firewall block? Port number is 3306 and firewall is off only

Comment: As said: the error message clearly says what the issue is. No sense in wildly guessing around if you know where the problem is. If you doubt that, then I suggest you add some debugging output as first line in the `Connect()` method and dump the values used in the call. You will see what? Indeed, that they are all empty. Now comes the question: _why_? And for that we have to take a look at where the values should come from. Just as said above.

Comment: It may very well be that the code is fine, but some settings in your environment are different to that other system when things work for you. But again, just as said in the last question: since you do not share any information about that there is nothing we can say. That is why your best bet is to start searching where the problem occurs. The goal is to find out _what_ is actually wrong here. That is something you have to find out, only you have access to your system. We may be good, but we are not that good to somehow magically feel what is wrong in your system...

Comment: Have you tried to disable your firewall! Everyone focus on the problem. Another issue may be you are using ipv4 to try to connect but your server is using ipv6, so you would have to add a loopback on your host file. Just another wild guesses...

Comment: Another thing, can you show where in your code you instance this `MySqlConnection` something like `$somevar = new MySqlConnection(param, param...)`

Comment: Hi Thank you all. Found the issue and it's fixed now. Issue is even though I dropped the database the booked_user was in the mysql db. Once I removed that everything works fine. Special thanks to arkascha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy and I am providing you a tested answer, first you need to build the Database class as seen below, you need to put it in a file and include it from your homepage (might be the index.php page). Then, you need to initiate an instance of your class from the homepage to connect to the database, the code is very well explained in details in this great article:  [www.muwakaba.com/php-database-connection](http://www.muwakaba.com/php-database-connection)

```
<?php
// Class definition
class Database{

    // The constructor function
    public function __construct(){
        // The properties 
        $this->host = "your_DB_host_address";
        $this->login = "your_DB_login_name";
        $this->password = "your_DB_password";
        $this->name = "your_DB_name";

        // The methods 
        $this->connect(); 
        $this->select();
    }

    // The connect function
    private function connect(){
        $this->connection = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->login, $this->password) or die("Sorry! Cannot connect to the database");
    }

    // The select function
    private function select(){
        mysql_select_db($this->name, $this->connection);
    } 

}
?>
```